# how to capture processing times of messages flowing thru MQ -> App -> Kafka -> App -> Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing, performance-measuring

I have systems pipeline as "IBM MQ queue --> Springboot app (Message Formatter) --> Kafka topic-1 (message queue) --> Springboot app (Message Transformer) --> --> Kafka topic-2 (message queue)".

My requirement is to test end to end processing time of messages generated in IBM MQ and processed thru the pipeline. I have a JMeter Load test script with JMS client that generates loads of messages pumped thru the pipeline.  Dynatrace Kafka monitoring is not yet implemented but Confluent Control Center for Kafka monitoring is used here.

Can you please suggest possible options to measure the individual and end to end processing times of messages processed by Springboot apps (Message Formatter and Message Transformer apps being deployed via DevOps Jenkins pipeline)?

Comment: Have you setup the Confluent interceptors on all components? Other options include distributed tracing

Comment: Not sure. will check and let you know.

Comment: If you have, then they all would appear in Control Center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can get the number of pending messages in the Kafka topic from JMeter itself using [Kafka Client Consumer](https://dzone.com/articles/writing-a-kafka-consumer-in-java) code from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Example code:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test"));
while(true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());

        // after each message, query the number of messages of the topic
        Set<TopicPartition> partitions = consumer.assignment();
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
        for(TopicPartition partition : offsets.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("partition %s is at %d\n", partition.topic(), offsets.get(partition));
        }
    }
}
```

The values can be stored into [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) using [`vars` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) and plotted into [JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) as custom charts.

Comment: The endOffsets aren't always the "number of messages in a topic", though

Comment: I really appreciate your help. If you guys have a sample JMeter test script for the above, can you please share me the same. I think, we need to have Kafka configs setup in JMeter to use the above code.